# How to use std::cout with mini-gmp mpz-t?

Tags: c++

Just as the title suggests, I'm having issues when trying to print `mpz_t` values using `std::cout` with mini-gmp.  I can use `mpz_get_si` to convert to an integer, and everything seems to be working, but this obviously defeats the purpose of gmp altogether.

When I use `std::cout` is seems to print the memory address of the `mpz_t` variable.  Does anyone have a solution for printing `mpz_t` values using mini-gmp?

Comment: Just as a follow up I know that I can use `mpz_get_str` to convert it to a character, and this does what I need it to do, but in regular gmp I am able to print `mpz_t` directly from `std::cout` , so I was just curious if this is possible in mini-gmp.

Answer (score 0):

By this documentation it seems that the class overrides cout as it is, so it should be supported https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Formatted-Output.html

Note: That could be feature loss due to mini-gmp vs gmp

although it does caution:

"But note that ostream output (and istream input, see C++ Formatted Input) is the only overloading available for the GMP types and that for instance using + with an mpz_t will have unpredictable results. For classes with overloading, see C++ Class Interface."

aside from that if you are getting a memory address where you think there should be a value, you could make sure you aren't actually dealing with a mpz_t* and simply dereference it and see if you get a type error. It's hard to tell without seeing any code

Comment: I am dealing with mpz_t , it's unfortunate that it has this problem since std::cout works perfectly with mpz_t in full gmp, but I need mini-gmp for what I'm using it for.